# How to put characters from a string into an array based version of an ADT stack

Tags: java, adt, stack

so for my assignment, I need to used the array-based version of the ADT stack to create a stack called myStack. I then need to create a string variable called str and assign it to the string "abcdefg" and access the characters in the string and push each character onto the stack, starting with the first. After all the characters are in the stack, I need to pop and display each of them on one line. Here is what I'm using:

```
public class StackArrayBased
{
  private static final int MAX_STACK = 7 ;
  private Object items [ ] ;
  private int top ;

  public StackArrayBased ( )
  {
    items = new Object [ MAX_STACK ] ;
    top = -1 ;
  }

  public boolean isEmpty ( )
  {
    return top < 0 ;
  }

  public boolean isFull ( )
  {
    return top == MAX_STACK - 1 ;
  }

  public void push ( Object newItem ) throws StackException
  {
    if ( ! isFull ( ) )
      items [ ++ top ] = newItem ;
    else
      throw new StackException ( "StackException on push: stack is full" ) ;
  }

  public void popAll ( )
  {
    items = new Object [ MAX_STACK ] ;
    top = -1 ;
  }

  public Object pop ( ) throws StackException
  {
    if ( ! isEmpty ( ) )
      return items [ top -- ] ;
    else
      throw new StackException ( "StackException on pop: stack is empty" ) ;
  }

  public Object peek ( ) throws StackException
  {
    if ( ! isEmpty ( ) )
      return items [ top ] ;
    else
      throw new StackException ( "StackException on peek: stack is empty" ) ;
  }
}
```

as well as:

```
public class StackException extends RuntimeException
{
  public StackException ( String s )
  {
    super ( s ) ;
  }
}
```

This is what I have so far, but I cannot understand why I'm getting exceptions and it isn't running correctly:

```
public class StackArrayBasedTester
{
  public static void main ( String [ ] args )
  {
    String str = "abcdefg" ;
    StackArrayBased myStack = new StackArrayBased ( ) ;
    Integer i = 1 ;
    Character c ;
    for ( i = 1 ; i <= 7 ; i++ )
      if ( ! myStack.isFull ( ) )
        myStack.push ( c = str.charAt ( i ) ) ;
    while ( ! myStack.isEmpty ( ) )
      System.out.print( " "+myStack.pop ( ) ) ;
  }
}
```

Is there any other way to do this?

Comment: Post the exception that you're getting. I notice that it seems like you're starting your iteration at `i = 1` instead of `i = 0`, but I'm not sure if that's the cause of your problem without the exception.

Answer (score 0):

What kind of exception are you getting?

`charAt` starts counting from 0. When you do `str.charAt(7)`, you'll get an IndexOutOfBoundsException.

Additionally, it might be better to loop on `i < str.length()`, in case you want to modify `str` hold a different value.

Comment: That was exactly what I was getting, I changed it to i <= 6, and made i = 0 and it worked perfectly. Thank you a lot, I appreciate it!